# How do we know EM fields are created by particles and not vice versa?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I'll start by stating that I'm not highly educated in the field (obviously, or I probably would not have asked the question).

EM fields, if I'm not wrong, are said to be created (not sure if that's the correct term) by acceleration of specific particles (e.g. electrons).

The question is quite simply, how do we know the cause is the electron acceleration and the effect is the EM field, and not vice versa - the cause is EM field which causes the particles to accelerate (and probably causes other phenomenons as well)?

Comment: See "pair production" the EM field can "produce" charges. The EM field can be non zero in the absence of charges so is not really correct to say it is produced by charges. Charges and the EM field interact with eachother

Comment: @jensenpaull so both charge can produce field and field produce charge? If so, what's the originator of them both? I assume it should be a third-party originator (sorry for the layman terminology)

Answer (score 2):

Before the time Maxwell united electricity and magnetism theories of the time into one set of differential wave equations, the observations of electric phenomena and magnetic phenomena had been described mathematically . At the time before Maxwell  no electromagnetic fields were known. The observations of electricity and magnetism and their relationship was encoded in a [series of laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations)

[Maxwell gathered these laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_SI_units_convention) into one mathematical format and discovered that light was also described by his theory. That is what is called the electromagnetic radiation, [visible light only  part of it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum)

You ask:

> EM fields, if I'm not wrong, are said to be created (not sure if that's the correct term) by acceleration of specific particles (e.g. electrons).

Electrons are elementary a particles following quantum mechanical equations. Charged particles of classical dimensions do radiate when accelerated, and better stick to this. .

> The question is quite simply, how do we know the cause is the *charged particle*
> acceleration and the effect is the EM field, and not vice versa - the cause is EM field which causes the particles to accelerate

Simply, at the classical level there has been no observation of light creating charged particles.

Now it can be shown that at the level of elementary particles and the theory of quantum electrodynamics Maxwell's equations emerge as [the classical limit of quantum electrodynamics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Maxwell%27s_equations_as_the_classical_limit_of_QED)

At the particle level electromagnetic waves emerge from a quantum mechanical confluence of photons, and for high energy photons your

> (and probably causes other phenomenons as well)?

new particles can be created  by interactions and there are such proposals of [gamma gamma colliders](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0510335) .

At the level of elementary particles, as the electron, one has to spend time studying quantum field theory in order to understand the subject.

Comment: So the point is, the fact that light is explained by Maxwell's theory which encompasses light under EM, and light doesn't create charged particles, means that EM doesn't create charged particles? Because if it did then light would've as well?

Comment: light is a very narrow frequency band as seen in the link I gave, and the frequency corresponds to photon energies that are too small to generate pairs of elementary particles. For gamma ray frequencies the energy is enough to generate particles but one has to study quantum mechanica and quantum field theory to get a handle on how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, electric fields are "particles" themselves, so neither would really be a good explanation, that is why when we want to understand the world we have more precise theories such as quantum electrodynamics (QED).

The other theories at the end are just good approximations that let us do computations with acceptable precision way more quickly than a QED computation would, but in some sense losing its real behaviour or physics.

In this concrete case what really is happening is we wave quantum excitations of the fermion (electrons, positrons...) and gauge (photons...) fields interacting between them creating net forces pulling and pushing this excitations between them. So in a sense yes, it goes both directions, fermion fields move gauge fields around and vice-versa.

Which in the more applied case you are dealing with, means that yes, electrons moving emit photons and vice-versa, photons accelerate electrons.

---

Edit: I just realized that maybe at the level you are asking the question, we really didn't need to go into QED to explain any of this (which is good anyway, so you see the most exact picture humans have right now).

But if what you were asking is not about self-interaction, but electric fields accelerating particles in general, it could have been explained way easier, in classical electromagnetism electric fields accelerate particles! You were just missing that the Lorentz Force exists:
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}=q (\vec{E} + \vec{v}\times \vec{B})
\end{equation} is the force an electric/magnetic field exerts on a particle with charge $q$ and velocity $\vec{v}$. And a force implies an accelertaion:
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}=m \vec{a}
\end{equation} so there you go, an electric field implies and acceleration on a particle!

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be in the context of classical electrodynamics. One well-known limitation of this theory is the inability to describe self-interaction, so the field generated by an electron cannot exert a force on it.

We know now, thanks to quantum field theory, that such self-interaction exists, but is mostly confined to very small scales which are outside the purview of classical electrodynamics.

In other words, an electron can't exert a force on itself.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is quite simply, how do we know the cause is the electron acceleration and the effect is the EM field, and not vice versa - the cause is EM field which causes the particles to accelerate (and probably causes other phenomenons as well)?

An astute question. In many radiative processes, the currents are themselves driven by electromagnetic forces. In a radio transmitter, we may consider that radiation from the antenna is due to a current. We may attribute the current to the electromagnetic field in the feedline. Perhaps the electromagnetic field in the feedline is due to the controlled current in a power amplifier. And so on. The currents and fields are so closely associated that cause and effect is murky.

However, in batteries and generators, electromagnetic forces aren't the only forces involved. Pauli forces due to the exclusion principle constrain electron motion and give the matter in these devices the solidity and  chemistry that make them work. In stars, nuclear energy accelerates charged particles, which can then give up their kinetic energy electromagnetically. In accretion disks around black holes, gravity is responsible for the motions that energize cosmic particle accelerators.

Comment: "In stars, nuclear energy accelerates charged particles, which can then give up their kinetic energy electromagnetically. In accretion disks around black holes, gravity is responsible for the motions that energize cosmic particle accelerators." This is the kind of answer I was looking for, but it still misses the point for me. Surely we note that nuclear energy and gravity accelerates the particles, but how do we know that this is what's being done, which causes the EM fields as a by-product of the acceleration; and not the other way around, nuclear energy and gravity creates the EM fields...

Comment: ... which then as a by-product accelerates the particles? Can we pin-pointedly trace the chain of events to know that the acceleration happens before the "creation" (I'm sure there's a better term) of the EM field? Or is it so simultaneous that we say that the acceleration causes the EM field as a heuristic reasoning?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Physics can't give you ultimate answers: all it can give you is models that work.

Comment: That much I know, I only ask if physics can currently answer *that* question, which doesn't seem "ultimate" to me. An answer of "no, we can not currently distinguish the event of acceleration and the event of the creation of EM fields in linear time" is acceptable and shows an honest limitation of current physics. There's nothing wrong with saying that the current model heuristically assumes that particles are the more fundamental part in this equation, by following atomism (which current physics does).